# why bad_alloc message show me after running my code

Tags: c++, memory, storage, tensor, bad-alloc

this code show the message "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc

Process returned 3 (0x3)   execution time : 0.331 s"
where is the problem I could not identify. I used codeblocks. Ram of my PC is 8GB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

ofstream bcrs_tensor;
bcrs_tensor.open("bcrs_tensor_Binary", ios::out | ios::binary);

int X=6187,Y=25,Z=78,M=33;



int new_dimension_1,new_dimension_2,new_x_1,new_x_2;
new_dimension_1=X*Z;
new_dimension_2=Y*M;

int* new_A = new int[ new_dimension_1*new_dimension_2 ];

vector<int> block_value,CO_BCRS,RO_BCRS;
block_value.reserve(303092010);
CO_BCRS.reserve(1554318);
RO_BCRS.reserve(37124);
cout<<"size"<<sizeof(block_value)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you build for x64 architecture, x32 has upper limit of 2GB and you are dangerously close to that.

Comment: `new int[ new_dimension_1*new_dimension_2 ]` requires approx 2GB of ram.  Your vector needs another 1-1.5 GB of ram.  Do you have enough to cover that, also knowing that these chucks need to be contiguous.

Comment: Is there any solution to solve the problem? @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @SafayetHossainSobuj yes - redesign your code to not allocate so much memory at one time.  Or else compile your code for 64bit systems.

Comment: @SafayetHossainSobuj on a side note - `sizeof(block_value)` will report the byte size of the `std::vector` class itself (which is small, say 12-24 bytes), it will not report the size of the `int` data that the vector is holding. For that calculation, you would need to use `block_value.size() * sizeof(int)` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I need this allocation because I am using a tensor data set of this dimensions

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I am using 64 bit system, still now, the error occurred

Comment: @SafayetHossainSobuj You don't need that much memory *at one time* to operate on that much *data*.  Process the data in smaller pieces.

Comment: Actually, I read the tensor value from e txt file. It put into a array then for further operation I need to store the row,column, value into vector. so is there any alternative solution? @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @SafayetHossainSobuj you did not show what you are actually doing with all of thos memory you are allocating, but properly designed algorithms rarely need to allocate 2GB of *memory* to process 2GB of *data*.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to allocate way more memory than your system has available for your app, so `std::bad_alloc` is being thrown, which you are not catching.

Assuming `sizeof(int)=4` in your compiler, you are asking for:

- **1.48GB** for `new_A`
- **1.12GB** for `block_value`
- **5.92MB** for `CO_BCRS`
- **145KB** for `RO_BCRS`

For a total of **2.61GB**.

Even though you have 8GB of RAM installed, your system does not have enough *consecutive* memory available to satisfy one of those allocations (ie, if it is a 32bit app, the whole process is limited to 2-3GB max, depending on configuration, memory manager implementation, etc.  But a good chunk of that is reserved by the OS itself, you can't use it for your code).

Comment: I am using 64 bit app. but How can I solve this problem? Please help me..

Comment: Even in a 64bit system, you are still asking for GBs of *consecutive* memory at a time, so there is still no guarantee the system can allocate such large amounts *consecutively*. Again, you really need to redesign your code to use less memory at a time.